# Batch Script for Checking time

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-line, command

Is it possible to check if the time is in between two ranges and then perform an action based on it.

For eg: I want to perform an action only when the current time **is not** in between 11.00 PM and 6.00 A.M.

Here's what I have so far but I am unable to pin the in between part.

```
set "currentTime=!TIME::=!" 
set "currentTime=!currentTime:,=!"
set "_bit_compare=leq"
set "compareTime=2300"
set "compareTime1=600"

(time /t | findstr /l "AM PM" || set "_bit_compare=gtr")>nul

if "!currentTime:~0,4=!" %_bit_compare% "!compareTime!" (

    do somethinf

)
```

Comment: The best way is to use a scripting language which uses dates as objects, not strings like batch/cmd. Powershell and Windows Scripting Host are built-in Windows scripting languages offering that functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is relatively easy to write using PowerShell. If you are on a supported Windows system, PowerShell will be available. This also overcomes a myriad of problems with regional variations in cmd.exe.

```
$h = [int](Get-Date -Format "HH")
if ($h -le 8 -or $h -ge 23) { & notepad.exe }"
```

To use it in a .bat file script, you could:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "$h = [int](Get-Date -Format "HH");" ^
    "if ($h -le 8 -or $h -ge 23) { & notepad.exe }"
```

Comment: Thanks. I get this error: At line:1 char:33
+ $h = [int](Get-Date -Format HH) ^
+                                 ~
Unexpected token '^' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecor
   dException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

'"if ($h -le 6 -or $h -ge 23) ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'{' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @CuriousDev - Sorry. I forgot to tell cmd that there are two (2) separate statements. Code is change. Please try again.

Answer (score 2):

And just to justify my comment, using [wsh](/questions/tagged/wsh), *([vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript))*, from a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```bat
<!-- :
@"%__AppDir__%cscript.exe" //NoLogo "%~f0?.wsf"
@If ErrorLevel 1 Exit /B
@Rem Your Commands go below here
@Echo Within range
@Pause
@Rem Your commands end above here
@Exit /B
-->
<Job><Script Language="VBScript">
        If Hour(Now())<=22 AND Hour(Now())>=6 Then
            WScript.Quit(0 Mod 255)
        Else
            WScript.Quit(1 Mod 255)
        End If
</Script></Job>
```

I have used `Rem`arks to show you where you put your command or commands, and have provided two lines for demonstration purposes, *(which you are free to remove once tested)*.

Comment: I like this as a good example of a hybrid script. But, why is `mod 255` needed on the exit code?

Comment: @lit, a little bit of laziness, I just copied and pasted a section from one of my scripts on an external drive, _(I don't have a PC, so it isn't often that I can borrow one for testing or checking my responses)_. I'm sure it should work properly with `WScript.Quit(0)` and `WScript.Quit(1)` or `WScript.Quit 0` and `WScript.Quit 1` too.

Answer (score 1):

It is a few lines more to do this in a batch file but you essentially want to get the time in a standard format. You can do that by calling out to WMIC.  I am just using the hour to compare.  I did not see any need to use minutes based on the provided example saying it is not in between 11.00 PM and 6.00 A.M. I am using a 1 to prefix the comparison incase of leading zeros in the hour.

```
@echo off

set "compareTime1=23"
set "compareTime2=06"

REM GET DATE and TIME
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
SET "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%"
SET "YY=%dt:~2,2%"
SET "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
SET "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
SET "HH=%dt:~8,2%"
SET "min=%dt:~10,2%"
SET "sec=%dt:~12,2%"

IF 1%HH% LSS 1%compareTime1% IF 1%HH% GTR 1%compareTime2% (
    ECHO LETS DO SOMETHING
)
```

Comment: Your script works great. Running a few more tests. Thanks!